# Retrieving module parameter settings in a template joomla 2.5

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm trying to get settings saved within a specific module in a specific template position in a Joomla 2.5 site to use in a module chrome I'm making for the website template. I'm not sure how this information can be retrieved. How is this done

Module: Newsflash, Position: banner

Would like to insert the code here

```
function modChrome_strHTML($module,&$params,&$attribs)
{
    //content to be manipulated here
}
```

Clarification

I am using the Newsflash Module to display specific news articles on the homepage.

I would like to manipulate the article content displayed in the module to match the structure I'm using in the site thus I am using the module chrome to get the article content and arrange it but I dont know how to access the parameters sent by the Newsflash module (the specified category) and other parameters so that I can use it in the module chrome. That is the help I am looking for.

I hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Would you mind to describe it more specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use JModuleHelper. It's hard to help more than that without knowing  what you are doing.